# C strcat garbage characters

Tags: c, cstring, strcat

I have a function in C where i am trying to get strings from two different locations (unknown size, could be quiet large) and combine them into one string and return them. If i just print the two strings then I get the correct result, but when I try to combine the strings using strcat I end up with 5 garbage characters and then the result of the combined strings.

Anyone have some advice as to what I am doing wrong? Here is some sample code to demonstrate what I am doing:

```
static int get_information(char** results)
{
    size_t s1_length;
    size_t s2_length;

    /* DEBUGGING - Prints the correct string */
    printf(get_string_1());
    printf(get_string_2());
    printf("\n");

    /* Allocate memory for new string */
    s1_length = strlen(get_string_1());
    s2_length = strlen(get_string_2());
    *results = malloc(sizeof(char) * (dir_length + file_length));

    if(results == NULL)
        return -1;

    /* Combine the strings */
    strcat(*results, get_string_1());
    strcat(*results, get_string_2());

    /* DEBUGGING - prints 5 garbage characters then the correct string */   
    printf(*results);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is dir_length and file_length?

Comment: `printf(get_string_1());` is better as `printf("%s", get_string_1());` in case the string has percentage characters in it.

Comment: Btw: `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1 by the C standard, so you can skip that.

Comment: @taskinoor - Sorry, that was part of the actual code that I missed converting while moving it to the sample code.

Comment: @Master of Disaster Thanks. @ChrisWue Also, thanks. :P

Comment: Show the code for `get_string_1()` and `get_string_2()`, please.

Comment: @kari Those are many many lines of code, none of which I wrote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`strcat` needs to find the null terminator in the destination. Your `*result` points to uninitialised memory, which happens to have a null terminator 5 characters in.

Adding `*result[0]='\0';` just before combining the strings should fix it.

Also, you are not allocating enough space for the null terminator in `*result`.

Answer (score 6):

Why do you `strcat` the first string? Simply copy it. Otherwise it will append to whatever garbage is in the uninitialized memory ...

```
/* Combine the strings */
strcpy(*results, get_string_1());
strcat(*results, get_string_2());
```

Answer (score 2):

strcat() assumes the destination to be a valid string, so make it so by adding

```
*results[0] = '\0';
```

before you do strcat()

Alternatively try doing these:

```
strcpy(*results, get_string_1());
strcat(*results, get_string_2());
```

Lastly, what exactly is happening in this line:

```
*results = malloc(sizeof(char) * (dir_length + file_length));
```

Make sure you allocate enough space to results. Ideally it should be:

```
*results = malloc(sizeof(char) * (s1_length+s2_length+1));
```

for allocating enough space as s1 and s2 and followed by a terminating '\0' character.